# Cropping Program draws two Rectangles every loop openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I could probably use some pointers on my programming style (VERY recently self taught in OpenCV/C++) but the problem on hand has to do with the drawing in my cropping program.

I click on a spot in the image, it draws a rectangle, then I can resize the rectangle and hit "z" to crop and save the image in a destination folder. But whenever I click anywhere in the program, it draws a new rectangle but keeps the most recent previous rectangle. So I constantly have 2 rectangles drawn at all times. I think this is maybe to do with how setMousecallback works but I am not sure. Blow is my code

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img;
string * strPtr;
int width, height;

void matResize(Mat& img){
    if(width > 600 && height > 600){
        int scale = width/600;
        width = width/scale;
        height = height/scale;
        resize(img, img, Size(width, height));
    }
}

void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        img = imread(*strPtr);
        transpose(img,img);
        flip(img, img, 1);
        width = img.cols;
        height = img.rows;
        matResize(img);

        Point* ptPtr = (Point*)param;
        ptPtr->x = x;
        ptPtr->y = y;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    ifstream file("/home/willem/Desktop/Training/ThumbsUp/img4resize/files.txt");
    //Read each file location into a vector array
    string str;
    vector<string> fileLocations;
    while (getline(file, str)){
        fileLocations.push_back(str);
    }

    //Loop to process each Image
    for(int i = 0; i < fileLocations.size(); ++i){
        //Square Properties
        Point2i pt(0,0);
        int X, Y;
        int hlen = 0;
        Rect rect;

        //Image name and rotation
        int found = fileLocations[i].find_last_of("/");
        int len = fileLocations[i].length();
        string tempstr = fileLocations[i].substr(found+1,len-1);
        namedWindow(tempstr);
        img = imread(fileLocations[i]);
        transpose(img,img);
        flip(img, img, 1);
        strPtr = &fileLocations[i];

        //resize to scale
        width = img.cols;
        height = img.rows;
        matResize(img);

        //Mouse Properties
        setMouseCallback(tempstr, onMouse, (void*)&pt);

        //Image update loop
        while(1){

            //Update MouseClick Position
            X = pt.x;
            Y = pt.y;

            //Set square properties
            if(X == 0){
                if(height > width)
                    hlen = (int)(height*(1.0/3));
                else
                    hlen = (int)(width*(1.0/3));

                rect = Rect(X-hlen,Y-hlen,2*hlen,2*hlen);
            }

            int waitKeyVar = waitKey(10);
            if(waitKeyVar % 255 == 129 || waitKeyVar == 133){
                //"q"
                //Skip image
                destroyWindow(tempstr);
                break;
            }
            cout << waitKeyVar % 255 << endl;
            if(waitKeyVar == 119 || waitKeyVar % 255 == 135){
                //"w"
                //Resize rect -5%
                hlen = hlen*0.95;
            }
            if(waitKeyVar == 101 || waitKeyVar % 255 == 117){
                //"e"
                //resize rect +5%
                hlen = hlen*1.05;
            }

            if(waitKeyVar == 122 || waitKeyVar % 255 == 138){
                //"z"
                //crop and save image
                Mat cropped = img(Rect(X-hlen,Y-hlen, 2*hlen, 2*hlen));
                string destination = "/home/willem/Desktop/AdMobilize/Training/ThumbsUp/New Positives/";             //Configure output here
                string final = destination + tempstr;
                imwrite(final, cropped);
                destroyWindow(tempstr);
                break;
            }

            //draw Rectangle
            rectangle(img, Rect(X-hlen,Y-hlen, 2*hlen, 2*hlen), Scalar(255,255,255), 2,8,0);

            //display Image
            imshow(tempstr, img);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: take a look sample application [opencv_annotation.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/apps/annotation/opencv_annotation.cpp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare and initialize int `waitKeyVar = 0;` outside of while loop and put 
put `waitKeyVar = waitKey(10);` at the bottom after `imshow(tempstr, img);`.

Last rectangle might be coming because you are showing image and putting `waitKey` at different position.

Comment: Have you actually tried this, or it's just a guess? In the first case, please provide a working corrected code, in the second case, this answer should probably be just a comment.